# How to iterate textfield From Two Different NSMUTABLEARRAY But index are same

Tags: iphone, ios

How to calculate and pick the value from two diffrent array on a same loop?

something like that

eg:

```
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray && textFieldArray2)
```

i have to subtract the value and i have 2 Array and i want to subtract the value of two textfield from different array but same index...

My code is

```
int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray) // will iterate all UITextField which was added
{
    result += [field.text intValue]; //or floatValue
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result); //here you have sum of all the text fields' text
```

i want to subtract this but both text fields are on different Array but have same index...

```
int y12 = ([Txt_New_Actual.text intValue]);
float c116 = y12-([Txt_New_Estimated.text floatValue]);
Txt_New_ONU.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",c116];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the index of the current object in your fast enumeration loop, then use `indexOfObject:` to get the index and use that with `objectAtIndex:` on your second array.

Something like this:

```
int result = 0;
for(UITextField *field in textFieldArray)
{
    int indexOfObject = [textFieldArray indexOfObject:field];
    UITextField *secondValue = (UITextField *)[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexOfObject];
    result += [secondValue.text intValue];
}
NSLog(@"the result is %d", result);
```

You should still put some kind of check into that code if the returned value from the 2nd array is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the enumerateWithBlock or have a variable index that you increment in the loop. Access the other array with objectAtIndex:.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is looping using a for clause instead of foreach, e.g.:

```
int result = 0;
int count = [textFieldArray count];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    UITextField field = [textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i];
    int y12 = ([field.text intValue]);
    field = [theOtherArray objectAtIndex:i];
    float c116 = y12-([field.text floatValue]);
}
```

Comment: No probs, I'm glad I could help. Please consider marking one of the answers as the answer for your question if they resolved your problem (not necessarily mine of course).